# Why Extended fab does not work? Any Ideas?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button, material-components, material-components-android

I'm trying to get run the Extended FAB for my activity, see Screenshot below. It just does not want to run. In my activity `xml` I use it as follows:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/create_ad_view"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/create_title_et"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_check"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton.Icon"/>
```

By the way, I used different sources and tutorials, even the official web site of Material Design with some details of using Extended FAB. This is my `dependency`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExtendedFloatingActionButton` was released with the [`1.1.0-alpha04`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases/tag/1.1.0-alpha04).

Use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is also valid. However, I could resolve this issue with the help of this `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'`

Comment: @MarkDelphi Yes, 1.1.0 and 1.2.0 contain both the ExtendedFab. 1.1.0 is close to a stable version, instead 1.2.0 is still an alpha release and it can be not yet ready for a production release.